# Количество пробелов от начала строки до начала текста

Tags: php

Как вычислить количество пробелов от начала строки до начала текста с помощью php?
Интересует решение в одну строку. 
Пример строки :

```
$str = '          семь пробелов от начала строки   а если  вот  такой   текст ?'
```

Comment: Достаточно. Только Ваш код на такую строку выдает 16

Answer (score 0, accepted):

С помощью регулярных выражений *(промежуточные пробелы не будут учитываться)*:

```
$str = '          десять пробелов от начала строки   а если  вот  такой   текст ?';
echo preg_match_all('~(?<=^|\G)\s+?(?=\s|\S)~', $str);
```

Результат: **10**

Comment: '$str = '          семь пробелов от начала строки   а если  вот  такой   текст ?'; '

Comment: Не могу написать в комментарии строку в которой кроме 7 пробелов в начале есть двойные и тройные пробелы в тексте. Тогда Ваш код неверно считает '$str ="          семь пробелов от начала строки   а если  вот  такой   текст ?" ' Другими словами  промежуточные пробелы Ваш код не учитывает пока они не двойные например

Comment: Вопрос тот же , пример строки добавил

Comment: @Taypfoon я обновил ответ.

Comment: Спасибо, аплодисменты !

Answer (score 0):

```
substr_count($stroka, ' ',0,strrpos($stroka, $starttext))
```

Comment: Это универсальное решение, я думал, что нужно узнать количество пробелов до определенного текста.

Answer (score 0):

```
$count = mb_strlen($str) - mb_strlen(ltrim($str));
```